# Jquery Array Push Strings Not Passing Through POST

Tags: php, jquery, array-push

I am trying to Pass a comma separated Id values to PHP using Jquery Post. I have below code in my Jquery

```
var values = [];
  $('tr#trdata td:nth-child(1)').each(function () {
  values.push("'"+$(this).html()+"'");
});
```

Above code is out putting value like this `'238','239','240','241','242','243','244','245','246'`

I am then Trying to post above value using below code

```
$.ajax({
      url : "mypage.php",
      method:"POST",
      dataType:"text",
      cache:false,
      data:{page_no:values, type: type, keyword: keyword},
                                                                
      success:function(data){
      }
});
```

And in my php I am trying to get the value with below code

```
if (isset($_POST['page_no'])) {
  $page = $_POST['page_no'];
}else{
  $page = 0;
}
```

I am getting the comma separated values in console correctly but in php it is always empty
what is the wrong I am doing?

Comment: `$_POST['page_no']` is empty not even comma separated values?

Comment: yes nothing is pass there

Comment: what about `$_POST['type']`? also empty with nothing in it?

Comment: $_POST['type'] is passing accurately, Even When I am trying to pass a hardcoded comma separated string like  var cc='200,300,400,500'; also not passing but when passing without comma separated it is passing

Comment: may i know the version of jquery being used?

Comment: 2.2.0 and 2.2.1